# Understanding DOM doctypes

Tags: jquery, dom, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to understand why, if I make this declaration on my aspx page...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

That in the DOM, it comes through like this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML Strict//EN">
```

The reason it's frustrating is that IE9 will throw it into IE7 standards and IE9 Compatibility mode.  In IE 8, it's fine and doesn't do this.  This is a big problem because it's breaks the app I'm creating until I force IE9 into IE9 Standards and I can't expect clients across a corporation to do this every time they use the app.

This app uses $.ajax calls, although this problem occurs at page load when jquery isn't being called yet.

When I do a simple view source and validate it, it's fine. No errors.  When I validate the "dom" source, it's a disaster.  Why??  A way to fix this or a work around?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While this might not be an ideal solution for you, what has come to work for me is just to use the following doctype. Deceptively simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

That's it!

There's probably reasons why that is a bad idea (or not what you want) but give it a try if you can in your situation and let me know if it disappoints.

Update:

Other things I've learned about this is that even an empty line or a comment prior to the doctype declaration can cause IE to throw its hands up.

Comment: Sorry, but still gives me this in the DOM.<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML Strict//EN">

Comment: This is often called the HTML5 doctype, for the curious.

Comment: Sorry John; I know your frustration. I updated my answer with another possibility. Hope you can find your answer.

Comment: It's cool, you tried. There are some control registers in the aspx that were causing the space you mentioned. Moved doctype above them, could see the spaces gone, in the static source at least, but the DOM source remained unchanged.

Comment: One more thought: if you haven't already, strip out everything in your document (or just create a blank one) with as little as possible. That way you can alleviate your concerns about ajax or other things getting in the way.

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER: Ah ha! This has to be the "first" entry in the head and it solves the problem. Being "first" is important as well, don't know why but I tried it multiple ways and that's the only way it will work.